# How to rasterize vector data correctly in GRASS GIS 6.4.0?

Tags: grass-gis

I try to rasterize some vector data in GRASS GIS 6.4.0. Unfortunately, it always just works with one layer. Afterwards, there are just lines generated instead of rectangles. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Without including the command that you used, it's hard to debug. However, did you specify `type=area` within the command?

Answer (score 1):

You (likely) need to set the computational region to the map of interest. See http://grass.osgeo.org/wiki/Computational_region for details.